# Web API authentication without username password

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, console-application

I've a simple web api configured for local authentication. This works fine.

I've a console application with httpclient implemented to consume the web api.

When the console app runs it sends credentials in header and receives token and normal operations work.

Since I want this app to run in background and want to keep the user intervention minimal, is there anyway I can do away with username/password without compromising on security aspects.?

Comment: It's not clear to me, what do you mean by *keep the user intervention minimal* ? what you want to do?

Comment: @Div since its a console app, I don't want admin to provide credentials every time server restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Passing on username and password through headers is not a security threat, what you can do to make them safe is encrypt them before sending and then decrypt on API side also make your Web API over `HTTPS` to make it more secure.

Comment: the concern is about convenience. I agree to your point about security. I am looking at possibilities of providing credentials at every restart.